# Calling parent's constructor in PHP

Tags: php, oop, subclass

I have the following two classes.

```
class Settings
{
    function __CONSTRUCT()
    {
        echo "Settings Construct";
    }
}

class PageManager extends Settings
{
    function __CONSTRUCT()
    {
        echo "PageManager Construct";
    }
}

$page = new PageManager();
```

I thought that would work fine, but it only runs PageManager's constructor. I'm assuming it's because I override the Setting's constructor. Is there some way I can call the parent's constructor as well?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just call it using parent::

```
    /* Settings */
class Settings{
 function __CONSTRUCT(){
  echo "Settings Construct";
 }
}

/* PageManager */
class PageManager extends Settings{
 function __CONSTRUCT(){
    parent::__CONSTRUCT();
    echo "PageManager Construct";
 }
}
```

Have a look at the [manual(Constructors and Destructors)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)!

Comment: it's better to call parent constructor before all instructions in child constructor, therefore we are sure that parent object is ready to use.

Comment: @Tomasz Kowalczyk Is it? Well I changed my answer to reflect this so thanks! :)

Comment: @Thomasz That entirely depends on what the parent and the child constructors are supposed to do. It's not *always* better.

Comment: @deceze - yes, you are right, but in most cases calling it first is better option, especially if we cannot see the base class implementation.

Comment: @Tomasz Kowalczyk Voted up :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition: you should know that this behaviour of PHP is not unique to the __construct() function.